# Invalid Keystore Format after creating a keystore and attaching a certificate to it

Tags: java, openssl

I am creating a keystore using OpenSSL using the following command :

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -in mycert.crt -inkey mykey.key \
                        -out mycert.p12 -name tomcat -CAfile myCA.crt \
                        -caname root
```

as per the [documentation](http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-6.0-doc/ssl-howto.html#Prepare_the_Certificate_Keystore).

Now when I try to validate the keystore using `keytool -list -v -keystore mycert.p12`, I am getting an `Invalid Keystore Exception`.

Is this because I am using Apache implementation of creating a keystore?

Also a constraint I have is that I cannot use Java keytool to create a keystore although my Java program is using to keystore for FTPS transfer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Use `-storetype pkcs12` option with `keytool`.

```
keytool -list -v -keystore mycert.p12 -storetype pkcs12
```

By default, `keytool` assumes that the keystore type is `JKS` and if it's not, `keytool` fails. If using other keystore files (`.p12` in your example), you need to explicitely give a store type using the mentioned method.

Comment: Yes Thank you this works although the command will be keytool -list -v -keystore mycert.p12 -storetype pkcs12 .Note '=' has to be removed.Thank you very much npe

Comment: Corrected. Glad I could help :-)

Comment: Thanks. In addition, I had to specify `-storepass <keystore_password>` in order to resolve "Password required" IO error...

Comment: The additional parameter "-storetype" is kind of mandatory for jdk versions 1.7. The problem does not seem to arise using jdk 1.8, as its keytool seems to automatically recognize the correct keystore format. TL;DR : if you use jdk 1.8 you can try omitting the "-storetype pkcs12" parameter .

Answer (score 1):

I was installed JDK 16.
I uninstalled JDK 16 after that I installed JDK 8

> jdk1.8.0_281

Thats worked!

Last version using another cyrpto format.

Comment: I used the full path to the correct version: `"C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_321\bin\keytool.exe" -list -v -keystore...`

Answer (score 1):

I used `where keytool`

to see that I had two keytools:

```
C:\Program Files\Eclipse Foundation\jdk-8.0.302.8-hotspot\bin\keytool.exe
C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-16.0.1.9-hotspot\bin\keytool.exe
```

In my case I solved it, by specifying the latter one:

```
"C:\Program Files\AdoptOpenJDK\jdk-16.0.1.9-hotspot\bin\keytool.exe" -list [...]
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by removing Java 1.7 from my machine. This made the Java 1.8 `keytool` the only available `keytool`. Since the Java 1.8 `keytool` supports `pkcs12`, the command worked.

Here is how to *remove Java 1.7* (on Windows 10 OS):

- go to `Windows Settings` => `Apps & Features`
- find all apps containing `Java 1.7` or `Java 7` in their name
- click on the app name and select `Uninstall`
- follow the uninstallation wizard for each of them
- **remove Java 1.7 from `PATH`**

**Note:** This might be achieved without uninstallation, only by placing the Java 1.8 path in the `PATH` variable *before/above* the path of Java 1.7, but I haven't tested this.

Comment: Turns out 1.8.0_20 is bugged. Swithcing to 1.8.0_144 solved the issue for me.